# update one table with data from another using the common key

Tags: sql, oracle

update one table with data from another using the common key

```
create table table1 (
  id varchar2(4),
  name varchar2(10),
  desc_ varchar2(10)
)


create table table2 (
  id varchar2(4),
  id_new varchar2(4)
)

insert into table1 values('1111', 'a', 'abc')
insert into table1 values('2222', 'b', 'def')
insert into table1 values('3333', 'c', 'ghi')
insert into table1 values('4444', 'd', 'jkl')

insert into table2 values('1111', '8080')
insert into table2 values('2222', '9090')

merge into table1 t1
using (select * from table2) t2
on (t1.id = t2.id)
when matched then update set t1.id = t2.id_new
```

> error: ORA-27432: step  does not exist for chain .

Comment: The reason is `Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated`,  you can use the same for no referencing column for merge

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
update table1 t1
set id = coalesce((
  select id_new
  from table2 t2
  where t1.id = t2.id), id);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3de8/1)

---

Here's an alternative approach with `merge`:

```
merge into table1 t1
using (select * from table2) t2
on (1 = 1)
when matched then update set t1.id = t2.id_new where t1.id = t2.id
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f457/1)

Answer (score 1):

Probably best speed you'll obtain using:

```
merge into table1 t1
using (select t1.rowid rw, t2.id_new 
       from table2 t2 
       join table1 on (table1.id = t2.id)
       ) s
on t1.rowid = s.rowid
when matched then update set t1.id = s.id_new;
```

However it depends on optimizer(previous answers may have a good behavior if CBO intuits your desire)